# How to use vlookup and countif together to get needed result

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I am trying to come up with result for the following problem:

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets - Report and Groups.
Report sheet has two columns - UPI and Disabled groups
Group sheet has three columns - UPI, Group Name and Status.

Every time I type 'Disable' in column Status I want that to reflect as count in sheet Report, column Disabled groups

I have been trying to combine vlookup and countif, but with no luck so far. Any ideas how to get to resolved?

Thank you!

Comment: Why the `vlookup`? It sounds like you need `countifs`: `=COUNTIFS(Groups!C:C,"Disable",A:A,Groups!A1)`. This makes the assumption that `C:C` is the Status column. `A:A` would be making sure whatever is in column A of "Report" (UPI or Group Name) are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Report Sheet has the UPI in column A, first row is headers, you can use this formula in column B

```
=countifs(Group!A:A,A2,Group!C:C,"disable")
```

in words: in the Group sheet, count all rows where column A has the same word as in cell A2 in this sheet AND the column D has the word "disable".

Adjust the formula to your scenario and copy down.

Comment: Amazing! That worked pretty good. Thank you so much :)